# How to obtain an App-Only Access Token to use with CSOM for SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, csom, authentication, azure

I have a multi-tenant Azure AD web application set up. This represents a scheduled task that needs to get a list of Site Collections from each one of (the web app's) SharePoint Online Tenants.

I am trying to achieve this by using CSOM as detailed in [this blog post](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2014-4-Get_list_of_site_collections_using_CSOM_in_Office365.aspx) from Sahil Malik.

The first step in the code in the blog post is a call to this method from the TokenHelper class:

```
public static OAuth2AccessTokenResponse GetAppOnlyAccessToken(
    string targetPrincipalName,
    string targetHost,
    string targetRealm)
```

1. What should I put in place of the `targetPrincipalName`? Where do I obtain this value for each one of my tenants?
2. Should my `targetHost` be the admin URL for each tenant? For example: "http://tenant1-admin.onmicrosoft.com/"?
3. Should my 'targetRealm' be null?

**Update:**
Having read through parts of the implementation of the `GetAppOnlyAccessToken()` method, I've realized I've been missing several `appSettings` that are required for it to work.

So far I've gathered the following but am still getting "(400) Token request failed." from SharePoint Online:

```
<appSettings>
    <!-- Guid to the left of @ in App Identifier (?) -->
    <add key="ClientId" value="..." />
    <!-- Not sure how to obtain this as: -->
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="..." />
    <!-- Guid to the right of @ in App Identifier (?) -->
    <add key="Realm" value="..."/>
</appSettings>
```

[image: App Identifier shown in SharePoint Online appprincipals.aspx page]

Am I missing any other appSettings? Am I correctly populating the ones above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question for future reference because I've been able to get the code working.

**Would love to see (and will accept) a more detailed response.**

Rather than use the identity of the Azure AD Web Application, I've started using the identity of a provider-hosted SharePoint Add-in. A part of my business solution is that each tenant will install this add-in anyway so it came in handy.

The code that worked for me:

```
var tenantAdminUri = new Uri("https://<tenant_name>-admin.sharepoint.com/");

var realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(tenantAdminUri);

var token = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(
    TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal,
    tenantAdminUri.Authority, 
    realm)
    .AccessToken;
```

And the following in app.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <!-- Guid to the left of @ in App Identifier -->
    <add key="ClientId" value="..." />
    <!-- Obtained when SharePoint Add-in created -->
   <add key="ClientSecret" value="..." />
</appSettings>
```

One important detail is to go into the SharePoint Add-in's `AppManifest.xml` and under the 'Permissions' tab to check the box that says "Allow the add-in to make app-only calls to SharePoint."